# Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.3 working with Array#collect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arraycollection

I have the following scope in my Order model:

```
scope :trial_almost_up, lambda { where :date_finished => 27.days.ago.midnight..27.days.ago.end_of_day }
```

Each order is tied to a User. So if you run Order.trial_almost_up and get an array of orders and run this:

```
o = Order.trial_almost_up
o.collect &:user
```

The collect runs a separate SQL statement for each Order that is tied to the user.

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11244 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1970 LIMIT 1
```

Is there anyway to combine this into one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. I don't know if there is a better way but this one is the only one that I can think of right now.

```
User.includes(:orders).where("orders.date_finished" => 27.days.ago.midnight..27.days.ago.end_of_day)
```

Let me know if it works, I'll edit this if I find something better

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! I forgot about using `includes`... still getting used to includes and join statements